# cocos2d Moving between scene

Tags: iphone, cocos2d-iphone

How to move between scene in cocos2d application. i have a bird which fly in the sky so how can i set the scene changing with different location in the application.

please help if anyone know the solution.

Comment: Do you want to move the bird, the background, or just switch from one scene to the next?

Answer (score 0):

Sounds like you want a Tile based game.  Here is a link to a great tutorial on how to implement a tile based game:
http://www.raywenderlich.com/1163/how-to-make-a-tile-based-game-with-cocos2d

Hope this helps.  Happy coding!