# cocos2d game development

Tags: iphone

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [cocos2d Moving between scene](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3083511/cocos2d-moving-between-scene)

Hi All,

Iam new in cocos2d game development, iam creating a game were a birds fly in the sky and there are obstacles which make bird crash when they collide with each other.

Now the problem is how do i change the scene from one scene to another which looks like bird flying continuously in the sky?

There is something that make object fly or run with background running.

Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

THIS IS A DUPLICATE QUESTION of [cocos2d Moving between scene](https://stackoverflow.com/q/3083511/485390) so I flagged it for moderation.

(Pasted my answer from the other question here anyway)

Sounds like you want a Tile based game.  Here is a link to a great tutorial on how to implement a tile based game:
http://www.raywenderlich.com/1163/how-to-make-a-tile-based-game-with-cocos2d

Hope this helps.  Happy coding!